# Umbraco cms AngularJS Regular Expression Keep appearing

Tags: angularjs, validation, umbraco

Umbraco uses angularJS as based library and backoffice totally developed on it. The reason telling first is to tell that I have a field on which URL regular expression applied. If someone entered invalid url like below image
[image]
it shows error as need.
But if a user try to remove whole text by selecting it and removing at once. It still keep appearing the error like this
[image]
However, if a user erase text one by one like this 
[image]
then the validation error removed and user need to click on button to see error again.

I would to know how screen 3 state can be achievable when user remove all text together? Its really annoying behavior for a user to remove text character one by one to refresh the state of the field. Screen 3 state should be applied on screen 2.

Can anybody tell me how it can fix or achievable? Right now, it seems like a default behavior.

Looking forward to hear from you guys. Suggestions will be much appreciatable.

Regards o

Comment: What is the umbraco version you're using?
Do you use a textbox with regex validation or some different data type? Please specify the data type and regex.

Comment: Hi @Marta I am using Umbraco 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this issue. This seems to be a product bug.

When you remove whole text at once, `newValue` is an empty string and the code responsible for resetting error messages doesn't run. If you have access to the umbraco code, you can easily fix it by removing highlighted check:

[image]